# Hovering Effect on Vizio Smart TV Application

Tags: jquery, css, html, smart-tv

In Vizio Smart TV app is showing a strange hover which is moving when a key is pressed. The desired key press functionality is not working properly whereas it seems Vizio's own hovering and navigation is taking place. i already used already tried a lot thing like setting border to none, removed hover, text formatting but all in vain.
Please suggest how to proceed.

Comment: Can we get anything to work with? Code? URL? Visuals? Anything? Cause now we are just guessing from a mere paragraph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hey i faced the similar problem and i resolved the problem by doing the following things

- Vizio platform tries to implement its own hovering where ever it will find `<a href>` tag in the webpage
- Vizio platform will implement hovering on textboxes and other input type in webpage

Actually vizio defines internal hovering which works on top to down basis in the 
eg suppose there is a code like this

```
    <div>
<a href="t1.html">test1</a>
<a href="t2.html">test2</a>
<a href ="t3.html">test3</a>
</div>
```

In the above case as soon as you will press the navigation key on remote hover will come up on test1 and once you will pressed right key it will shift to test2 and so on and vice versa will happen in case of left key

Note: way to avoid this hover is remove a href tags in the app, atleast i did it in my app

Comment: that can be a reason let me give it a try